# Boost Asio - ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

i have installed libboost-dev  and libboost-asio-dev and etc.

In the ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10 have got same problems with asio, in example:

‘connect’ is not a member of ‘boost::asio’

its a sync_client from examples.

Others boost's libs seems to work fine. Is there any particular way to use ASIO?

Comment: Show us the source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

boost::asio::connect was only added in boost version 1.47. Try an [older version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp) of the example. In general, the Ubuntu versions of boost are a couple of versions behind the boost releases.

Comment: For Ubuntu 11.04 the version of Boost is 1.42 (unsure about this, may have been 1.40 even!), and for 11.10 the version is 1.46. So `boost::asio::connect` is definitely not available.

Comment: Thank you, i hadnt thought that there may be so much changes in 1.47. ( there is 1.46 in ubuntu respo)